# pushing files into local git server

Tags: git, nginx, push

I've set up a local git server using nginx and i've been able to pull files but i haven't been able to push them back, i always get the following error:

```
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database objects
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To https://localhost/git/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://localhost/git/repo.git'
```

Any help on what could be the cause of the problem and how it could be fixd?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to push via `http`. `http` is a read only protocol so you cant push with this protocol,

Change the url to `https` and you will be able to write to the repository - it will prompt you to enter password or set your `ssh` keys using: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email"`and then add it to your remote server.

From this point you can use ssh to push.

---

#### Summary:

http is a read only so you need to use ssh or https.

Comment: tested but still didn't work, added the same fault with https